# Where does the girl from episode 15 end up in the next episode?

Tags: sliders

At the end of episode 15 (in Season 2, as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sliders_episodes)) titled *El Sid*, Sid's girlfriend slides again together with all the others, but then in the next episode she is no longer there.

Am I right or am I just watching the episodes in the wrong order? If I am right where did she go?

[image]

Comment: Season 2 has only 13 episodes.. when you say "2-15" you mean season 2 episode 15?

Comment: sorry that's how the episodes are defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sliders_episodes. I guess it's number 15 in absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you provided, Fox aired the shows out of order.
Episode 15 *El Sid* should have been followed by Episode 14 *The Good, The Bad and The Wealthy*.
However, from the episode summaries ([link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/tv/sliders/episode-guide/)), there is no mention of Sid and his girlfriend anywhere other than episode 15.

Comment: That is actually my problem. even if you watch them in order, Sid's girlfried just disappear